# Counting animation stuck when decimal values verse

Tags: javascript

I've gotten this animation function from a different post

```
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var range = end - start;

    var minTimer = 50;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(duration / range);
    stepTime = Math.max(stepTime, minTimer);

    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var endTime = startTime + duration;
    var timer;

    function run() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var remaining = Math.max((endTime - now) / duration, 0);
        var value = end - (remaining * range);

        obj.innerHTML = (value).toLocaleString('en', { maximumFractionDigits: 16 });
        if (value == end) clearInterval(timer);
    }
    var timer = setInterval(run, stepTime);
    run();
}
```

Which works great! I update the values every second which works fine, until the values drops and there are decimals involved. at which point the counting bugs out, i think this happens because of the timing which isn't perfect. How would I solve this? I can't seem to figure it out.

You can view the bug here: https://jsfiddle.net/rrnop6q6/

Comment: I don't understand the issue. It counts between the start and end values just fine and then stops counting? Please post an example that completely replicates the issue

Comment: "until the values drops" - I don't get what you mean here. Drops where? Below what?

Comment: Yeah, I could not get it to "bug out" aswell: https://jsfiddle.net/zgejjmzd/1/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I'm sorry I should've provided an example, you can view it here https://jsfiddle.net/rrnop6q6/

Comment: Thanks, that's helping. Can you describe the "bug out"? It seems to be working as expected.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon it can take some time for it to happen (maybe something like 10 seconds?), I think that when it happens you'll know what I mean. But anyway the counter just stops 'animating' and stands still for a second, and then jumps and that repeats itself.

Comment: I think that only happen when the 2 randoms are close to each other. If you look at the code, you can see that the delay between steps depends on both values. Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/rrnop6q6/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I see, would there be a way to solve that?

Comment: You could set the `stepTime` to a static variable.  https://jsfiddle.net/rrnop6q6/2/